# Multiple selected2 dropdown for every row in datatables

Tags: php, laravel-livewire

I'm currently doing my mini project. The web view of the blade should be like multiple select2 dropdown in each row of datatables and user should select an option from them. The problem that I'm facing right now is that the select2 dropdown is getting the latest value(id) inserted into wire:model="fruits" (I already made public $fruits = [ ]; inside my controller). Is there any way that can store all the selected value inside the wire:model?

1. Blade view

```
@foreach($majorfruits as $data)
     <tr>
        <td>
             <x-forms.select wire:model="fruit" id="fruit-id-{{$loop->iteration}}" >
                     <x-slot name="option">
                            @foreach ($fruits as $item)
                                        <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </x-slot>
             </x-forms.select>
         </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

2. jQuery of select2

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                $('#fruit-id-' + i).on('change', function (e) {
                    var data = $(this).select2("val");
                    console.log(data);
                    @this.set('fruit', data);
                });
            }
```

Comment: where is defined the select2 element as multiple?

Comment: Even though I put multiple in the <x-forms>, the wire:model="fruits" only take the latest change. Also I don't want the user to select more than one for all the select2 in the rows of datatables. Just one value(id) for each row. @Prospero

Comment: then fruit don't need be declared as array. also, why the jquery function is into a for loop?

Comment: The jquery is into a for loop is becasue id the <x-forms> need to make the id unique for every row in datatables. @Prospero